# How to send many SMS using Java android code?

Tags: java, sms

I am creating a program which is capable of sending sms from PC to mobile phones. It doesn't matter whether it is sending SMS using an online gateway or using the dongle (but, u know, sender's original number will be there only if we use a dongle, isn't it?). Most examples in internet I found are written in 2006-2010 and they all use JavaMail and Java Communication API, and the communication api is almost missing at the moment, probably oracle gave it up.

I am seeking for some technology, which is upto date and up and running. This is my first attempt in such. I am very much glad to see tutorials. Thank you

Comment: Could you maybe give some links to examples you've tried?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you check http://www.kannel.org/ and  http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/05/java-api-for-kannel-smswap-gateway-v_24.html

Comment: @Jayan: Thanks for the Kannel. But, what should I pass to the place where "localhost" is displayed? Do you know any web address to pass there? Please help!

Comment: "Not a Real Question" blah blah blah..So what is the real question? Please provide a universal recognized definition..If no answer, "closed as not a real question ". Please can someone go and tell to the scientists who search about aliens, "Close the project, it is not a real question, difficult to answer" ? I am glad to see it

Answer (score 4):

After doing few Try & Error, i created following code a year ago, it is working fine. It uses GSM Modem to send SMS. Your GSM Modem should be connected to your Comm Port. You would be requiring Comm.jar library to run this code, You can download it from http://llk.media.mit.edu/projects/picdev/software/javaxcomm.zip

My code is simple programmtic version of firing [AT Commands](https://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&safe=off&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=AT+Commands&oq=AT+Commands&gs_l=hp.3..0l10.1133.7051.1.7196.13.8.1.4.4.1.896.3823.3-1j3j2j1.7.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.ygQm59f64go&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=3f7e71b5cbd4d390&biw=1366&bih=667). It simply fires AT Command on GSM Modem to send SMS.

```
import javax.comm.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class SimpleWrite implements Runnable, SerialPortEventListener
{
    public void run()
    {}

    static Enumeration portList;
    static CommPortIdentifier portId;
    static String messageString = "";
    static char ch = '"';
    static String dest = ch + "111111111" + ch;  // 10 Digit Mobile Number.
    static InputStream inputStream;

    static SerialPort serialPort;
    static OutputStream outputStream;

    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event)
    {
        switch (event.getEventType())
        {
        case SerialPortEvent.BI:
        case SerialPortEvent.OE:
        case SerialPortEvent.FE:
        case SerialPortEvent.PE:
        case SerialPortEvent.CD:
        case SerialPortEvent.CTS:
        case SerialPortEvent.DSR:
        case SerialPortEvent.RI:
        case SerialPortEvent.OUTPUT_BUFFER_EMPTY:
            break;
        case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:
        {

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line = "";
            try
            {

                while ( (line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                System.err.println("Error while reading Port " + e);
            }
            break;

        }
        } //switch
    }

    public SimpleWrite(SerialPort serial)
    {
        try
        {
            inputStream = serial.getInputStream();
            try
            {
                serial.addEventListener(this);
            }
            catch (TooManyListenersException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Exception in Adding Listener" + e);
            }
            serial.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception in getting InputStream" + ex);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String line1 = "AT+CMGF=1\r\n";
        String line2 = "AT+CMGS=" + dest + "\r\n";
        String line3 = messageString + "\r\n";
        //String line1 = "AT+CREG=2";
        //String line2 = "AT+CGREG?";

        portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
        while (portList.hasMoreElements())
        {
            portId = (CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();
            if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL)
            {
                if ( portId.getName().equals("COM11"))
                {
                    System.out.println("SMS Sending....Port Found");
                    try
                    {
                        serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("SimpleWriteApp", 2000);
                        SimpleWrite wr = new SimpleWrite(serialPort);

                    }
                    catch (PortInUseException e)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Port In Use " + e);
                    }
                    try
                    {
                        outputStream = serialPort.getOutputStream();
                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Error writing to output stream " + e);
                    }
                    try
                    {
                        serialPort.setSerialPortParams(9600,SerialPort.DATABITS_8,SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
                    }
                    catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException e)
                    {
                    }
                    try
                    {
                        outputStream.write(line1.getBytes());
                        outputStream.write(line1.getBytes());
                        outputStream.write(line2.getBytes());
                        outputStream.write(line3.getBytes());
                        outputStream.write(26);
                        outputStream.flush();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Error writing message " + e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /** show text in the text window
     * @param Text text string to show on the display
     */
    public static void showText(String Text)
    {
        System.out.println(Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply :). But, when I run this, nothing happened?

Comment: there is a DLL in the zip. Is this is platform dependent?

Comment: anyway, System.out.println(portList.nextElement()); gives null. why? I have a dongle!

Comment: which operating system you are using ?

Comment: well it should work, though i have developed code in XP.

Comment: hmmm, but, is that is a problum in my side? I mean, the PORT is not detected. I am having Huwawai dongle

Comment: may be, is it showing in your device manager ?

Comment: @Lucifer i have used your programme but didn't responded by sending sms, please tell me other configurations required for running this programme.

Comment: @Aniket, sure, tell me in detail, what have you tried ?

Comment: @Lucifer i will tell whole set up of application. i want to send sms from my j2ee application.where i have used GSM modem(Micromax) and sim card(Aircel) connected to USB port (COM3), when i am trying to send sms using your given example it is just printing line in console as "SMS Sending....Port Found" nothing happen except that.what is actual problem where i am going wrong...

Comment: @Lucifer still i doesn't able to send message through gsm modem, waiting for your please help...