# how to send sms from pc to mobile in J2ME

Tags: java-me, sms, midp, wma

I have a Java me midlet which can send group message repeatedly, it worked well on my WMA console. How could I deploy it so that it can be tested on a real device?

Moreover, what should I do to let it send sms from PC to mobile?

Answer (score 0):

For the deployment of J2ME Application ( .Jad & .Jar ) following ways can be used,

- Connect Device with PC by USB cable or bluetooth and transfer the files,
- Put your .Jad & .Jar file on live ip based server and download on the device using live ip+file name as path in device's browser

For more information on J2ME Application's deployment, visit following link
http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_install_Java_ME_application_in_mobile_phone

For sending sms from pc to mobile see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12605880/996493).

Comment: Thanks so much, Lucifer! Thant helped me a lot. Now I have two methods in mind. One is send sms through GSM modem and the other is through the SMS gateway API.Which you suggest me to implement this?

Comment: That you can choose based on your requirement.