# Sending bulk sms using sms manager in android

Tags: android, sms

I am sending sms nearly to 90-100 number's using `SmsManager`, I am reading number's from file and passing the number to sendtextmessage function as below

```
String[] nos;// this array contains mobile nos
SmsManager sm = Smsmanager.getDefault();
for(int i=0;i<nos.length;i++){
 sm.sendtextmessage(nos[i],null,"hello",null,null);
}
```

problem is:

1. Code is executing but messages are not sending, even I am having balance
2. I changed code to use stock sms app to send even this also failed to send.
3. if I send one to one no from stock app, it is sending but if I choose number more than 5 then it is not sending I used htc explorer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is right but the problem is that you are firing SMS in a for loop. The for loop is going to execute very fast while Sms Sending action requires some delay before sending a next SMS.

Previously I have done same kind of program in Java, you may find it's working code in my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12605880/996493). So during my development I come to know that SMS sending activity requires a time gap before sending next SMS. So I would like to suggest you to have a delay of atleast a 1000 micro second before sending the next SMS.

Comment: hello lucifer, thanks for your reply, i will try this.