# How to read incoming messages from GSM Modem in JAVA

Tags: java, serial-port, gsm, modem

```
 package pack1;

 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.*;

 import javax.comm.*;

  public class Java_SerialCommTest1 implements Runnable, SerialPortEventListener
 {
 public void run()
  {}

  static Enumeration portList;

  static CommPortIdentifier portId;
  static String messageString = "My Message to be sent";
  static char ch = '"';
  static String dest = "*********";  // 10 Digit Mobile Number.
  static InputStream inputStream;

  static SerialPort serialPort;
  static OutputStream outputStream;
    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event)
  {
    switch (event.getEventType())
    {
    case SerialPortEvent.BI:
    case SerialPortEvent.OE:
    case SerialPortEvent.FE:
    case SerialPortEvent.PE:
    case SerialPortEvent.CD:
    case SerialPortEvent.CTS:
    case SerialPortEvent.DSR:
    case SerialPortEvent.RI:
    case SerialPortEvent.OUTPUT_BUFFER_EMPTY:
        break;
    case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:
    {
                     try
         {
             inputStream = serialPort.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line = "";
            line = reader.readLine();

            while ( line != null)
             {

                        System.out.println(line);
                               break;
            }               
            if(line.contains("SM"))
            {
               System.out.println("if it contains SM");
               String messagepos= line.substring(6);
               System.out.println(messagepos);


             String recievedmessage = "AT +CMGR=" + messagepos + "\r\n";


                outputStream = serialPort.getOutputStream();
                outputStream.write(recievedmessage.getBytes());
                outputStream.write(13);


            }
            if(line.contains("REC"))
            {
               System.out.println("**********REC Data*************");

               System.out.println(line);

            }

        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.err.println("Error while reading Port " + e);
        }
       break;
    }
    } //switch
     }

    public Java_SerialCommTest1(SerialPort serial)
     {
            try
    {
        inputStream = serial.getInputStream();
        System.out.println(inputStream);
        try
        {
            serial.addEventListener(this);
            serial.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);

          }
        catch (TooManyListenersException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception in Adding Listener" + e);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception in getting InputStream" + ex);
    }

      }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchPortException, IOException
    {
    String line1 = "AT +CMGF=1\r\n";
     String line2 = "AT +CMGS=" + dest + "\r\n";
     String line3 = messageString + "\r\n";
            portList=CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
            System.out.println(portList);
     // System.out.println(portId);
    while (portList.hasMoreElements())
    {
                    portId = (CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();
        if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL)
        {
                            if ( portId.getName().equals("COM6"))
            {
               System.out.println("SMS Sending....Port Found");
                try
                {
                    serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("SimpleWriteApp", 2000);
                    Java_SerialCommTest1 wr = new Java_SerialCommTest1(serialPort);
                                        }
                catch (PortInUseException e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Port In Use " + e);
                }
                try
                {
                    outputStream = serialPort.getOutputStream();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Error writing to output stream " + e);
                }
                try
                {
                serialPort.setSerialPortParam (4800,SerialPort.DATABITS_8,SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
                }
                catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException e)
                {
                }
                try
                {
                        outputStream.write(line1.getBytes());
                    outputStream.write(line1.getBytes());
                    outputStream.write(line2.getBytes());
                    outputStream.write(line3.getBytes());
                    outputStream.write(26);


                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Error writing message " + e);
                }
                finally
                {
                     outputStream.flush();

                }
            }
        }
      }
      }

         /** show text in the text window
      * @param Text text string to show on the display
           */
        public static void showText(String Text)
     {
           System.out.println(Text);
        }

     }
```

Output ***************************************************

----------------------At main----------------------
----------------------At main 2----------------------
SMS Sending....Port Found
---------------message Writing-----------------------

140
OK

---------------case Data Available-----------------------
---------------line=reader.read-----------------------
 "SM",15

15 //I extract the 15 out of SM message
//Keep that 15 for AT +CMGR=15,, returns this

**********REC Data*************
 "REC UNREAD","+Mobile no",,"14/01/23,16:02:06+22"
-> Here the SMS Data Should come !!!

I have taken help from this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/12605880/2537945. but iam unable to read the incoming messages as it only returns me the REC ** Line but not the actual message which comes after this REC ** Line. Could you help me with any other solution or how to read Incoming messages in GSM Modem

Comment: download Hercules to better undestand of SMS structure .
http://new.hwg.cz/files/download/sw/version/hercules_3-2-6.exe

Comment: output.write(line1.getBytes());
                        output.write(line1.getBytes());
                        output.write(line2.getBytes());
                        output.write(line3.getBytes());
                        output.write(26);
                        output.flush();
data i am getting from serialEvent() is ok ok ERROR.

Answer (score 0):

i am running this and i am sending sms

```
public class PScanner implements SerialPortEventListener, Runnable {

    CommPortIdentifier pid = null;
    SerialPort sp;
    BufferedReader input;
    OutputStream output;



        static char ch = '"';

        static String dest = ch + "**********" + ch;
        String line1 = "AT+CMGF=1\r\n";
        String line2 = "AT+CMGS=" + dest + "\r\n";
        String line3 = "hello" + "\r\n";


    public PScanner() {
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    public void read() {
        try {

            Enumeration e = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
            while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
                CommPortIdentifier cpi = (CommPortIdentifier) e.nextElement();
                if (cpi.getName().equals("COM11")) {
                    pid = cpi;
                    break;
                }
            }
            sp = (SerialPort) pid.open(getClass().getName(), 2000);

            sp.setSerialPortParams(115200, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
            InputStream is = sp.getInputStream();
            input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            output = sp.getOutputStream();
             output.write(line1.getBytes());
                        output.write(line1.getBytes());
                        output.write(line2.getBytes());
                        output.write(line3.getBytes());
                        output.write(26);
                        output.flush();

            sp.addEventListener(this);
            sp.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
        System.out.println("serialEvent CallBack");
        try{
         if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE){
            String line = "";
            while ((line = input.readLine())!= null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }   
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }



    }

    public synchronized void close() {
        if (sp != null) {
            System.out.println("not null");
            sp.removeEventListener();
            sp.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        read();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PScanner.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            System.out.println("done");
        }
    }
}
```